# Having issues with working with socket.io and mediastream api to send realtime, live audio chat between clients in a room

Tags: javascript, audio, server, socket.io, mediastream

I am having an issue that I can't seem to figure out. I am creating an application in which clients in a room will be able to talk to each other via their microphone. So more specifically, I need to stream audio from one client's microphone, send the data (while it is being recorded) to the server and then to a different client so that they can can hear the other persons voice in real-time. I have a method of doing this, but it is inefficient, choppy, and blatantly bad...

My method as of now:

This snippet is on the client side of the person recording audio

```js
setInterval(() => {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then(stream => {
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.start();
    const audioChunks = [];
    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", (event) => {
      audioChunks.push(event.data);
    });

    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
      socket.emit('liveAudioToServer', audioChunks)
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      mediaRecorder.stop();
    },2000);
  });
}, 2000);
```

This snippet is the server side:

```js
socket.on('liveAudioToServer', (data) => {
    socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('liveAudioToClient', data)
})
```

And this snippet is the client side on the receiving end of the audio:

```js
socket.on('liveAudioToClient', (data) => {
  const audioBlob = new Blob(data);
  const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
  const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
  audio.play()
})
```

Basically, what this code does is it sends an audio buffer every two seconds to the server and then the server broadcast the buffer to the other clients in the room. once the other clients receive the buffer, they compile it into audio that is played. The main issue with this is that you can clearly tell when the audio ends and begins and it is not smooth in the slightest. However, I tried a different solution that with some tweaking I feel like it could work. But it doesn't work as of now..

Other Method:

```js
if(navigator.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.getUserMedia(
        {audio: true}, 
        function(stream) {
          const audioContext3 = new AudioContext();
          const audioSource3 = audioContext3.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
          const analyser3 = audioContext3.createAnalyser();
          audioSource3.connect(analyser3);
          analyser3.fftSize = 256;
          const bufferLength = analyser3.frequencyBinCount;
          const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
          function sendAudioChunks(){
              analyser3.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);
              requestAnimationFrame(sendAudioChunks);
              socket.emit('liveAudioToServer', dataArray)
          }
          sendAudioChunks();
        },
        function(){ console.log("Error 003.")}
      );
    }
```

server side:

```js
socket.on('liveAudioToServer', (data) => {
        socket.broadcast.to(getRoom(socket.id)).emit('liveAudioToClient', data)
    })
```

other clients side (receiving audio)

```js
socket.on('liveAudioToClient', (data) => {
    const audioBlob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(data)])
    const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
    const audioo = new Audio(audioUrl);
    audioo.play()
  })
```

I've really looked everywhere for the solution to this and I have had no luck so if anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated!!!